# Swift: How to Make Https Request Using Server SSL Certificate

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, https

Hi I want to make Https Request in Swift. Currently im accessing local server through ip address. Local Server has one SSL Certificate by accessing the certificate want to make request to server currently im doing like this.

```
  Alamofire.request(.GET, https://ipaddress//, parameters: [param], headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")


            }
    }
```

I have used the above code for making request and in plist

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
        <key>192.168.2.223:1021(my local ip)</key>
        <dict>
        Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
           <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests-->
           <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
           <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

in plist i have given like this but im still getting error like

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

Comment: You can't use IP addresses in the ATS plist values.

Comment: Did you get solution?

Answer (score 6):

IMPORTANT: DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION. Basically, with Alamofire, you can bypass the authentication for app development and testing purpose. Make sure you remove it before the app is on the App Store or in production:-

```
func bypassURLAuthentication() {
        let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
        manager.delegate.sessionDidReceiveChallenge = { session, challenge in
            var disposition: NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition = .PerformDefaultHandling
            var credential: NSURLCredential?
            if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
                disposition = NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential
                credential = NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
            } else {
                if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
                    disposition = .CancelAuthenticationChallenge
                } else {
                    credential = manager.session.configuration.URLCredentialStorage?.defaultCredentialForProtectionSpace(challenge.protectionSpace)
                    if credential != nil {
                        disposition = .UseCredential
                    }
                }
            }
            return (disposition, credential)
        }
    }
```

Thank You! 
Let me know if this helps. :)