# Alamofire 4 FAILURE With Swift 3.0 : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 “cancelled”

Tags: ios, https, request, swift3, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire for a https connection.

However when testing in Alamofire I get this error:

```
URLError occurred: URLError(_nsError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://192.168.X.XX/VMSSite/Handlers/Common/iOSServer.ashx?RegID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://192.168.X.XX/VMSSite/Handlers/Common/iOSServer.ashx?RegID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}) status code: nil
```

My source looks like this:

```
    var defaultManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
            let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
              "192.168.X.XX:443": .disableEvaluation,
              "192.168.X.XX": .disableEvaluation
            ]

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30 //seconds
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        //defaultManager = SessionManager(configuration: configuration, delegate: SessionDelegate(), serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))
        defaultManager = SessionManager(configuration: configuration, serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))

        defaultManager.request("https://192.168.X.XX/VMSSite/Handlers/Common/iOSServer.ashx?RegID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)

     var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode

        if let error = response.result.error as? AFError {
            statusCode = error._code // statusCode private
            switch error {
            case .invalidURL(let url):
                print("Invalid URL: \(url) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            case .parameterEncodingFailed(let reason):
                print("Parameter encoding failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
            case .multipartEncodingFailed(let reason):
                print("Multipart encoding failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
            case .responseValidationFailed(let reason):
                print("Response validation failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")

                switch reason {
                case .dataFileNil, .dataFileReadFailed:
                    print("Downloaded file could not be read")
                case .missingContentType(let acceptableContentTypes):
                    print("Content Type Missing: \(acceptableContentTypes)")
                case .unacceptableContentType(let acceptableContentTypes, let responseContentType):
                    print("Response content type: \(responseContentType) was unacceptable: \(acceptableContentTypes)")
                case .unacceptableStatusCode(let code):
                    print("Response status code was unacceptable: \(code)")
                    statusCode = code
                }
            case .responseSerializationFailed(let reason):
                print("Response serialization failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                // statusCode = 3840 ???? maybe..
            }

            print("Underlying error: \(error.underlyingError)")
        } else if let error = response.result.error as? URLError {
            print("URLError occurred: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Unknown error: \(response.result.error)")
        }

        print("status code: \(statusCode)") // the status code
     }
}
```

I'm using Swift 3 and Alamofire 4.0 from the xcode8.1 branch.
Please help me.

And

How to set value for Exception Domains in ATS for dynamic hostnames?

Note: If i am using bypassURLAuthentication with this code its working fine with https. but as per post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098485/swift-how-to-make-https-request-using-server-ssl-certificate/40722362#40722362) bypassURLAuthentication is not recommended to use for PRODUCTION. so i need help to solve this issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42985488/746347

Answer (score 0):

use this:-

```
Alamofire.request("https://192.168.X.XX/VMSSite/Handlers/Common/iOSServer.ashx?RegID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", method: .post, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

 switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                if let data = response.result.value{
           print("your response data \(response.data!)")

                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print(response.result.error)


                break

            }


}
```

Comment: i had tried this but want make request with SSL (serverTrustPolicies) that's why i can't use Alamofire.request if you see my code i had used sessionmanager to call request with that i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to your defaultManager instance. Otherwise, the session manager gets deallocated before the response is returned. See here for more info: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/157

Answer (score 0):

make your **defaultManager** global property for your class.