# Certificate Invalid Issue with Alamofire 4.0

Tags: ios, ssl, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to consume web services for my iOS app over https. The web server uses a self signed certificate.

When consuming the web service, I get the error “certificate is Invalid”.

> FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “portal” which could put your confidential information at risk."

I know the best practise is to fix this at the server side to enable a trusted root CA. But as this is a temporary development environment, we are using a self signed certificate.
Since this is ATS issue, I have edited ATS in my info.plist as below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>devportal</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As the NSException domains doesn’t work with IP and port number, I have created a host entry in my etc/hosts file for the web server IP and consuming it like https://devportal:8443/rest/login instead of consuming it as https://192.22.xx.xxx:8443/rest/login

I have followed alamofire documentation on server trust policies, edited ATS to allow exception domains but nothing worked out for me. I have spent over 3 days on this issue. Am I missing something? Does anybody faced a similar issue? Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance

I am using almofire 4.0, Xcode 8.0. Below is my code.

```
class LoginService{
     private static var Manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {

          let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "192.22.xx.xxx", ofType: "crt") // Downloaded this certificate and have added to my bundle
          let localCertificate:NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)!

          // Create the server trust policies
          let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
               "192.22.xx.xxx": .pinCertificates(
                    certificates: [SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate)!],
                    validateCertificateChain: true,
                    validateHost: true
               ),

               "devportal:8443": .disableEvaluation
          ]

          // Create custom manager
          let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
          configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
          let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(
               configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
               serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
          )

          return manager
     }()



     /**
      Calls the Login Web Service to authenticate the user
      */
     public func login(username:String, password: String){

          let parameters = [
               "username": "TEST",
               "password": "PASSWORD",
                  ]
          let header: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json"]
          LoginService.Manager.request("https://devportal:8443/rest/login", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding(options: []),headers :header).responseJSON { response in
               debugPrint(response)

               if let json = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(json)")
               }
          }



     }
}
```

Comment: Is your test device configured to trust the self-signed certificate? This can be verified in iOS Settings -> General -> Profiles.

Comment: @Rein I am not testing it in a device at this point, as it is not test ready. I have just started development and running it on a simulator.

Answer (score 15):

I modified my code like below and it worked. I referred [Swift: How to Make Https Request Using Server SSL Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098485/swift-how-to-make-https-request-using-server-ssl-certificate?answertab=oldest#tab-top) for fixing this issue.

```
       class LoginService{
             private static var Manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
           
                  // Create the server trust policies
                  let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
                      
                       "devportal:8443": .disableEvaluation
                  ]
        
                  // Create custom manager
                  let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
                  configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
                  let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(
                       configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
                       serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
                  )
        
                  return manager
             }()
        
        
        
             /**
              Calls the Login Web Service to authenticate the user
              */
             public func login(username:String, password: String){
    
    // Handle Authentication challenge
        
          let delegate: Alamofire.SessionDelegate = LoginService.Manager.delegate
         delegate.sessionDidReceiveChallenge = { session, challenge in
              var disposition: URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = .performDefaultHandling
              var credential: URLCredential?
              if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
                   disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential
                   credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
              } else {
                   if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
                        disposition = .cancelAuthenticationChallenge
                   } else {
                        credential = LoginService.Manager.session.configuration.urlCredentialStorage?.defaultCredential(for: challenge.protectionSpace)
                        if credential != nil {
                             disposition = .useCredential
                        }
                   }
              }
              return (disposition, credential)
         }
    
//Web service Request    
                  let parameters = [
                       "username": "TEST",
                       "password": "PASSWORD",
                          ]
                  let header: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json"]
                  LoginService.Manager.request("https://devportal:8443/rest/login", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding(options: []),headers :header).responseJSON { response in
                       debugPrint(response)
        
                       if let json = response.result.value {
                            print("JSON: \(json)")
                       }
                  }
        
        
        
             }
        }
```

You should also configure your plist as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>devportal</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

> Do not enter IP or port numbers in your NSExceptiondomains. It won't
> work. If you are trying to connect to a web server with IP address,
> map the IP address to a domain by adding a host entry in etc/hosts
> file in your mac and then use the domain name in NSExceptionDomains
>
> **IMPORTANT:** Do not use this code in production as this puts your users
> information at risk, by bypassing auth challenge.

Comment: Beautiful! I didn't need to update my plist. Instead I generated a root CA, created leaf certs, generated pems, installed root cert on device, etc. with the instructions provided by Apple at: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1948/_index.html. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

***Not suggesting for production use-cases***

```
//Use this manager class
class APIManager {
    static var Manager: Alamofire.Session = {
        let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["your endpoint": DisabledTrustEvaluator()])
        let session = Session(serverTrustManager: manager)
       return session
    }()
}

//Call APIs using this manager
APIManager.Manager.request("API")
```