# Unable to make request using Alamofire due to- TIC SSL Trust Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I have set- Allow Arbitrary loads to YES

And I am using the following code to fire a request:

```
let apiAddress = somehttpsAddress
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30 // seconds
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30 //seconds
AFManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
AFManager.request(apiAddress , method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { response in
            // utility
}
```

However all I get is these errors:

```
TIC SSL Trust Error [1:0x60c000161c80]: 3:0
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

I don't understand what's missing here and how should I correct this. Please help me in correcting this.

Comment: You might want to check this thread https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2512#issuecomment-387428459

Comment: @Xchord, does that mean I cant do the same?

Comment: The Alamofire doesn't support it yet. You can use URLSession as discussed here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92231or configure the authentication properly on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to some public network or maybe campus network, they may have installed some restrictions softwares for instance Cyberoam. The address on which you are making request might be restricted. you can ask for the permission to access that particular site.

Comment: Actually, it is an insecure link. Not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that Alamofire think it's not a valid ssl certificate. Try to use this as your manager:

```
    private static var Manager : Alamofire.SessionManager = {
    // Create the server trust policies
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "your domain goes here": .disableEvaluation
    ]
    // Create custom manager
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    let man = Alamofire.SessionManager(
        configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )
    return man
}()
```

Comment: No error, in fact it doesn't even connect with the link now. status code is plain nil

Comment: Weird, try with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40784254/5135104 by changing both the plist and the code as described please

Comment: Worked for me! Even without `.pList` entries.